# how do I make my site timezone aware?

Tags: django, timezone

I have an app that uses

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.now()
default=datetime.now
auto_now=True
auto_now_add=True
```

I'm changing the above codes to the below.

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now() # instead of datetime.datetime.now()
default=timezone.now # instead of datetime.now
auto_now # override save() or pre_save() .. ok don't need this change in recent django.
auto_now_add # override post_save() to set time when `created`.. don't need this change either
```

Am I missing something or doing something superflous?

I'm using an open source app and it uses a lot of datetime.datetime ..
It's really pain to change all that.. hope there was an easier way.

Comment: I checked django 1.4.5 source code, and auto_now and auto_now_add uses timezone.now() instead of datetime.now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings file you have to set `USE_TZ = True`. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/):

> Time zone support is disabled by default. To enable it, set USE_TZ =
>   True in your settings file